# Puppet dynamic variable from hostname

Tags: regex, puppet

I am looking at trying to get a dynamic variable out of my ec2's hostname. Hostnames follow this pattern

```
us-east-1b-application-type-environment-138-10.domain.com
```

I would like my variable to end up looking like this

```
application-type-environment
```

Using this

```
$variable = regsubst($hostname, '/[a-z]{1}[0-9]{1}-([^-]+)-[0-9]{1,3}/', '')
```

I end up with this though

```
us-east-1b-application-type-environment-138-10
```

How can I get my expected outcome?

Comment: Try `regsubst($hostname, '^[^0-9]*[0-9][a-z]-(.*?)-[0-9]{1,3}.*$', '\1')`. It seems you do not need regex delimiters here, and you need to match the whole string to be able to remove it and only keep what you need. I think you are trying to get just what is in between the first [digit][lowercase-letter]  chunk and a three digit chunk.

Comment: @stribizhev awesome, make sure to post that as the answer so i can accept!

Comment: Done please check, I will also add a regex explanation when I am at my desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need regex delimiters in [`regsubst`](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/2.7.3/function.html#regsubst). You need to match the whole string to be able to remove it and only keep what you need. The techique consists in matching what you do not want to keep and matching and capturing what you do want to have asa result.

You can use

```
regsubst($hostname, '^[^0-9]*[0-9][a-z]-(.*?)-[0-9]{1,3}.*$', '\1')
```

I think you are trying to get just what is in between the first [digit][lowercase-letter] chunk and a three digit chunk.

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jL1uK9/1)

Breakdown of the expression:

- `^` - start of line (if start of string is meant, replace with `\A`)
- `[^0-9]*` - 0 or more non-digit symbols (all but digits, this can be replaced with `\D*`)
- `[0-9][a-z]-` - a digit followed by a lowercase letter followed by `-` (the same as `\d[a-z]`)
- `(.*?)` - match and capture any characters but a newline as few as possible before the closest...
- `-[0-9]{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits (the same as `\d{1,3}`)
- `.*$` - 0 or more any characters but a newline up to the end of line (if end of string is meant, replace with `\z`).